# Errors while calling images from dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create dictionary of images with their names as follows. I am getting following errors (shown as a comment above the line with the error).

ViewController.swift

```
var selectedImages = [String : UIImage ]()

let cityImages: [String : UIImage] = [ "City00" : UIImage(named: "city_00")!  , "City01" :UIImage(named: "city_01")!, "City02" : UIImage(named: "city_02")!]


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        as! CollectionViewCell

    // Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
    cell.imageView?.image = self.selectedImages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showOptions"
    {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
        var indexPath = indexPaths[0] as IndexPath
        let CityVC = segue.destination as! CitySelectViewController

        // Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
        CityVC.imageSelected = self.selectedImages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
    }
```

How do I get rid of these errors?

This is `CitySelectViewController.swift`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.imageSelected.count

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        as! CityCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image =  imageSelected[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    cellImage = imageSelected[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cellImageName = imageSelected[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
}
```

Comment: The first error is because you are using an integer as the key for a dictionary that has `UIImage` keys.  The second one has the same issue as well as also having extra `[]` around it.

Comment: It seems that you need an array of city names and then you should use the string city names as the key to a dictionary of `[String:UIImage]`. A dictionary on its own isn't a good match to a collection view since it is unordered.  You should also use `indexPath.item` rather than `.row` for a collection view

Comment: @Paulw11, I did as you told and still I am getting this Ambiguous error. I just edited my question to my present solution

Comment: Now you have two dictionaries, not a dictionary and an array

Comment: @dan, I changed keys and removed []. Still I am getting error as in my edited question

Comment: @Paulw11, I am now confused. Isn't String = key and UIImage = vlaue

Comment: Now you're using an integer as a key for a dictionary that has `String` keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries aren't a very good match with `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` as they are unordered; this means that you can't index then with an integer index (Unless you are using an Int as the key, but this is effectively an array) and if you enumerate the keys or values, the order in which those keys or values are returned is undefined.

Your addition of the second view controller clarifies your real question; you want to send more than one piece of information to the second view controller.  I am still not entirely clear what the purpose of the second view controller is, and since you are using another collection view, I assume you want to be able to pass multiple selected cities, although your segue seems to be triggered on a single selection, so that won't work at the moment.  I have shown the code that passes the multiple selections regardless

You should create a `struct` to hold your city data and use an array of that struct:

```
struct City {
    var name: String
    var imageName: String
}

class firstViewController: UIViewController // Or UICollectionViewController 

let cities = [City(name:"City00", imageName:"city_00"),
              City(name:"City01", imageName:"city_01"),
              City(name:"City02", imageName:"city_02")]


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    as! CollectionViewCell

    let city = self.cities[indexPath.item]

    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:city.imageName)

    return cell
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showOptions" {
        if let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
            if let cityVC = segue.destination as? CitySelectViewController {
                var selectedCities = [City]()
                for indexPath in indexPaths {
                    selectedCities.append(self.cities[indexPath.item])
                }
                cityVC.selectedCities = selectedCities
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your `CitySelectViewController`

```
class CitySelectViewController {

    var selectedCities = [City]()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.selectedCities.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    as! CityCollectionViewCell

        let city = self.selectedCities[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named:city.imageName)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let city = self.selectedCities[indexPath.item]
        cellImage = UIImage(named: city.imageName)
        cellName = city.name
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason, I wanted to use dictionary was to save name of image when an image is selected in collectionview.

Comment: You can just store a string array and use `UIImage(named:)` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`; preloading the images into a dictionary just uses more memory and doesn't save any time

Comment: I just added my other viewController and the reason, I was creating dictionary. I am new to the swift, any suggestions based on that would be appreciated as I am able to understand everything you said clearly until now.

Comment: I have edited my answer, but it isn't clear exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I learnt a lot from your explanation, I thought I can do it but now I included what all I got in the code above. How do I deal with this situation where I have two different areas and different set of images

Comment: You could put your array for each section into another array and divide your collection view into sections.  You can ask another question if you need specific help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130460/discussion-between-leaner122-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary uses UIImage as a key and maps it for String value. Usually you wish to do it another way, like that

```
var selectedImages = [String : UIImage]()
```

If you add images in format City0x then you can get your image like so

```
let imageName = "City0" + String(describing: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
let image = self.selectedImages[imageName]
```

Then you have your image and you can do whatever you want.
But if you get those images by using only indexPath's row I'd suggest such changes

```
var selectedImages = [UIImage]()

let image = self.selectedImages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
```